# Unexpected behaviour of JavaScript with let and var keyword

Tags: javascript

When i am using var keyword to declare a variable then JS engine is assign default value to "message" at creation stage

```
console.log(message); //undefined       
var message = "My message";
```

but with let keyword

```
console.log(message); //message is not defined       
let message = "My message";
```

why this unexpected result or it is something changed in ES6?

Comment: Related to hoisting, see https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/javascript-hoisting-var-let-const-variables/

Comment: Nothing is _changed_ in ES6; `let` was introduced in ES6.

Comment: Because 'var' is a function scoped where as 'let' is block scoped. So you can access 'var variable' within the function that  is why it is giving output as undefined. And 'let variable'  scope will start after you define it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the creation of [Temporal dead zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone) with `let`

> `let` bindings are created at the top of the (block) scope containing the declaration, commonly referred to as ***"hoisting"***. Unlike variables declared with `var`, which will start with the value `undefined`, `let` variables are not initialized until their definition is evaluated. Accessing the variable before the initialization results in a `ReferenceError`. The variable is in a ***"temporal dead zone"*** from the start of the block until the initialization is processed.